# What books or papers contain a comprehensive intro to Hermite polynomials?

Tags: measure-theory, reference-request, soft-question, hilbert-spaces, hermite-polynomials

I am interested in Hermite polynomials for my study of Ito-Wiener expansion, as they are mentioned to have close relations with each other, but I'm acquainted with the former a little bit only, especially in the framework of Quantum Mechanics. So I have a strong need for a good description of Hermite polynomials in relation with Measure theory in Hilbert spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an extensive bibliography of Hermite polynomial references in [Hermite Polynomial](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HermitePolynomial.html). However, my go-to reference for most functions is K. Oldham, J. Myland, & J. Spanier, *An Atlas of Functions*, Springer . Chapter 24 covers the Hermite polynomials.